# Automated option to make bars to show their result

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(1, 1, 8, 32, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Is there any automated option to make the bars show there results with a clear way even if their frequency is 1 like the year of 2012?

Comment: You could add `check_overlap = T` to `geom_text`.

Comment: By the way if you use `geom_col()` you can save yourself typing `stat = "identity"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no ideal solution to showing this tidily on a plot. You could use `geom_label_repel` from `ggrepel`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_label_repel(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

or facet with free scales:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_wrap(.~Year, drop = TRUE, nrow = 1, scales = "free") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Or perhaps a `facet_zoom` from `ggforce`:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  ggforce::facet_zoom(ylim = c(0, 50))
```

[image]

Or have floating labels:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(data = within(Data, Frequency[Year == "2006-07"] <- NA), size = 3, 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_label(data = Data[1:4,], aes(y = 1:4 * 100), 
            position = "stack"
```

[image]

Personally, I think I'd go with a table here...

Comment: Very nice options!